# How do you reset an AS3 list component so that nothing is selected (NOT selectedIndex=0)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, combobox, flash-cs4, selecteditem

I have a list component on the stage in an AS3 movie. I populate it with values at runtime and the user can select multiple values.

When a button is clicked I want the list to reset to a state where nothing is selected, all I can figure out is to set the selected index to 0 and have the first position on the list either blank or reading "choose from the list" and make the code ignore this if it is selected.

Is there a way to reset list (and combobox components) to nothing selected.

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK I found it:  selectedIndex = -1